# Puppet-Labs Apache Module Set Operating System type

Tags: centos, puppet, vagrant

I'm new to Puppet and having some trouble with the Puppet-Labs Apache Module http://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/apache.  I'm using it in conjunction with Vagrant as a serverless setup (if that changes yours answer.)

In my entry point I call the apache.pp class which looks like this:

```
class {'apache::mod::php': 
   case $::operatingsystem {
     'RedHat', 'Fedora', 'CentOS', 'Scientific', 'SLC', 'Ascendos', 'CloudLinux', 'PSBM', 'OracleLinux', 'OVS', 'OEL': {
     }
     default: {
      $osfamily = $::operatingsystem
      }
    }
  }
```

However when I run puppet I get a syntax error:

```
Error: Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '::operatingsystem';    expected '}' at /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests/classes/apache.pp:2
```

I've headed down this route because during the debug runs earlier I discovered that puppet was attempting to use "apt" on a centos box.  I assumed that I needed to set the os type per the puppet labs "types" info on the puppet forge page.

Only other thing I should note for those unaware of working with vagrant, the *.pp are shared from the host system which is Debian in this case.  Could that also be a cause?  I don't think it would be.

I apologize if this is a dumb question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need to set the operating system in any way - Facter handles that.  Run `facter` on the system to verify that it's setting the facts correctly.

What version of Puppet are you running?  It seems to be choking on the use of `$::` as an explicit specification of the top scope, which should work just fine in any recent version.

Comment: Hi Shane - I was just about to follow up.  I'm running 3.1.1.  I discovered partially that I had dumby issue.  When using vagrant, all modules are set on the host's machine.  So - I was missing the stdlib and firewall modules for it to run.